# RestKit object mapping failing in one project but not in Twitter example

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rest, restkit

Learning RESTKit.

Step 1: I have successfully run the Twitter example project.

Step 2: I have successfully modified the Twitter project to point to my own REST webservice... REST is able to interpret the results successfully, and map them to a custom object I built.

Step 3: I have created my own project space and copy-pasted the working code from Step 2 into this project with some minor edits, and strangely enough, RESTKit is failing to properly map the results.  I am going crazy at this point.

Turning on the handy debugging traces included in RESTKit, both projects get to here:

```
2012-08-12 21:06:14.145 RKTwitter[9087:13003] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:320 Performing object mapping sourceObject
```

But Step2 Project gets this as the next message:

```
2012-08-12 21:06:14.294 RKTwitter[9087:13003] T restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:278 Examining keyPath '' for mappable content...
2012-08-12 21:06:14.301 RKTwitter[9087:13003] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:261 Found mappable collection at keyPath ''...
```

whereas my Step3 project gives up and dies:

```
2012-08-12 21:10:40.912 DogPark[9127:13203] D restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:351 The following operations are in the queue: ()
```

Rolled up my sleeves, and I have determined the precise point where the difference in code execution occurs within RESTKit:

In `RKObjectMappingProvider.m`, line 160 is the following method:

```
- (id)valueForContext:(RKObjectMappingProviderContext)context {
    NSNumber *contextNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:context];
    return [mappingContexts objectForKey:contextNumber];  
}
```

Which for Step2 returns a dictionary with 1 element in it, whereas my Step3 project returns a dictionary with 0 elements in it.  This dictionary is used in `RKObjectMapper.m`, at line 332, where the foundMappable is either true for Step2 project or false for my Step3.

```
if ([mappingsForContext isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        results = [self performKeyPathMappingUsingMappingDictionary:mappingsForContext];
        foundMappable = (results != nil);
```

Here is the code that seems correct but doesn't seem to want to run properly:

```
// init the Object Manager
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:SERVER_ADDRESS];
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;

// Mapping
RKObjectMapping *ownerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass: [DogOwner class]];
[ownerMapping mapKeyPath:@"DogOwnerId" toAttribute:@"dogOwnerID"];
[ownerMapping mapKeyPath:@"DogName" toAttribute:@"dogName"];
[ownerMapping mapKeyPath:@"OwnerFirstName" toAttribute:@"ownerFirstName"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setObjectMapping:ownerMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/DogOwner"];

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath: @"/dogowner" delegate:self];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add some api data sample?

Comment: yeah, I guess I will have to provide a lot for this question to be answered.  I was trying to see how I could even ask the question so it would be productive.  I'm wondering if there is some kind of a compiler switch in the Twitter project that I need to look at.  This bug is so obscure.  I will add more details this evening.

Comment: well, I don't really understand why there were differences in behaviours between the two projects, but I changed everything around and now it works.  

Changed my usage of:

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setObjectMapping:ownerMapping forResourcePathPattern:@"/DogOwner"];

to 

[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:ownerMapping forKeyPath:@"ArrayOfDogOwner.DogOwner"];

and, specified the input to be xml rather than json.  RestKit was able to figure it out code-magically within Step2, so I'm not sure if XML / JSON was the issue.  Who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the very comical narration to your problem.

One mistake was specifying a mapping to `/Dogowner` and trying to load `/dogowner`. Your comment above also gives two other huge problems

1. xml and json are not interchangable
2. your source keypath was wrong.

Comment: I agree with your comments... huge problems for sure.  Even after this post where I thought I got it working, I still had problems.  Compounding it was that the REST Service was also not functioning properly, making debugging the client impossible.  I have noticed as well that RestKIT seems to have synonyms for the same functionality, but I'm not sure.  ie: you can have [objectManager.mappingProvider registerMapping:ownerMapping withRootKeyPath:@"dogOwner"]; as well as [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:ownerMapping forKeyPath:@"dogowner"];"  What's the difference?